# CTL vs normal distribition of residuals

Tags: bootstrap, residuals, normality-assumption, central-limit-theorem

[image][image]Hello,
I submitted a study with a linear regression model. My sample size is >1000, so I invoked CTL.
The statistics reviewer is requesting that we check assumptions of normal distribution (specifically normal distribution of errors), and if not met, he/she recommends that we switch to logistic regression using one of our binary predictors as the outcome.

The residuals of my original model are NOT normally distributed per Shapiro Wilks (see picture). The skewness and kurtosis are 1 and 4.5, respectively. The suggested logistic regression shows no significant predictions. I also tried linear regression with outcome transformed to square root, with minimal "improvement" in skewness and kurtosis (0.8 and 2.5, respectively, but still non-normal per Shapiro Wilks).

Can I make an argument to favor my original model - linear regression - despite non-normally distributed errors, by invoking CTL?
Any other way to adjust these results?
Thank you!

Update 1: thank you so much for your suggestions. I have added the requested q-q plot of the residuals for the original model.

We did a bootstrap to our original model. In our results, we are planning to report:

1. the observed coefficients
2. either the percentile or the bias-corrected 95% CI
3. can we still report the p values of the bootstrap model? (Audience preference)

Is there another diagnostic to run after this? Should this be sufficient to mitigate the concerns of the reviewer regarding violation of normality?

Thank you!!

Comment: the suggestion of abandoning the continuous response by switching to logistic regression if normality of residuals cannot be met is absurd. (Not that you can write in your rebuttal "people on CV think that's a dumb idea"... but just thought you should know). It's true that you've got a few high-flying points out there. But why not just switch to a inference method that doesn't use distribution assumptions? Are you comfortable with the bootstrap?

Comment: Thank you. I thought so too. I am not comfortable with boostrap but I can ask one of my partners about it. I am hesitant to dropping my outliers because they are real data, not input errors.

Comment: Can you also include in your post a qqplot of the residual?

Comment: @Alstor yes, you should of course not drop the outliers. If you don't like the idea of bootstrap, you could also consider a robust regression with robust standard errors for the coefs. For instance, python's statsmodels implements inference for Huber regression (https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/examples/notebooks/generated/robust_models_0.html), which is outlier resistant.

Comment: Although the model might be improved, the relatively large number of observations, the bounded nature of the responses, and the lack of extreme skewness imply the CLT does apply here.  But perhaps the clearest way to demonstrate this to a reviewer who might not understand that would be with a quick bootstrap.

Comment: thank you so much for your suggestions. I have added the requested q-q plot of the residuals for the original model.

We did a bootstrap to our original model. In our results, we are planning to report:

the observed coefficients
either the percentile or the bias-corrected 95% CI
can we still report the p values of the bootstrap model? (Audience preference)
Is there another diagnostic to run after this? Should this be sufficient to mitigate the concerns of the reviewer regarding violation of normality?

Thank you!!